Show that the given map is continuous in a Hausdorff space
Let $E$ is an $n$-dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space and $F$ is any topological vector space. If, $\{e_1, \cdots,e_n \}$ any basis for $E$ and $T: E \to F$ is linear map, then show that
$$S:=(\lambda_1 , \cdots , \lambda_n) \in \mathbb{K}^n \to \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j T(e_j) \in F \quad (\mathbb{K}^n \,\,\text{scalars)}$$
is linear and countinuous. As a consequence of this, $T$ is continuous.
I tried to find any map $R$ such that $T = S \circ R$ and to be $S$ and $R$ continuous. Can you give me any help or advice or any other way to showing this problem. Thanks for your attention.

$S$ is by definition the map that sends $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ on $\sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_kv_k$ where for all $k$, $v_k = T(e_k) \in F$. The way the $v_k$ are defined doesn't matter and $S$ is continuous whatever are the $v_k$ by definition of what is a topological vector space (the exterior product and the sum are continuous maps).
Then, set $R : E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ to be the isomorphism (of vector spaces) that sends each $e_k$ on $(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ where the $1$ is at the $k$-th position. Clearly, $T = R \circ S$ so we have left to show that $R$ is continuous.
Let $N$ be any norm on $\mathbb{K}^n$ (it defines its topology) and $B \subset \mathbb{K}^n$ the closed unit ball. By the same argument as previously, $R^{-1} : \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow E$ is continuous thus the restriction $R^{-1} : B \rightarrow R^{-1}(B)$ is continuous too. Any continuous bijective map from a compact set to a Hausdorff topological set is a homeomorphism hence $R : R^{-1}(B) \rightarrow B$ is continuous.
To conclude, if $U$ is an open subset of $E$, up to a non zero homothety (which is an isomorphism), we may assume that $R(U) \subset B$ thus $U \subset R^{-1}(B)$ and $R^{-1}(U)$ is open by continuity of $R : R^{-1}(B) \rightarrow B$. We deduce that $R$ is continuous on the whole $E$.
By the way, it proves that $R$ is a homeomorphism hence the Haussdorff topology on $\mathbb{K}^n$ is unique and comes from norms. In particular, $E$ is a metric space.
